# OnShown or any other event for data template item when it displayed in windows 8 metro apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, datatemplate

I am developing windows 8 metro style application. My application contain page with following data template. i bind "NewsObject" collection to template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewsOverlayDataTemplate">
        <Grid Height="250" Width="250">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <Binding Path="IsView" Converter="{StaticResource headerColorConverter}"/>
                </Grid.Background>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="10,3,10,0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Style="{StaticResource NewsTitleTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="BlueViolet" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Grid  Margin="10,2,10,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Provider}" Height="14" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="9" Opacity="0.49"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Height="14" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="9" Opacity="0.49">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding Path="Time" Converter="{StaticResource dateFormatConverter}" ConverterParameter="year"  />
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
```

initially "NewsObject" only load its "Title" & "Time" properties. but when each item shown i want load items "Description" also. "Description" getting from server side by sending request. to send that request i need "Onshown" or any other event when each item displayed(Scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

If your content is displayed in an ItemsControl (like a ListView) with the default ItemsPanel that supports UI virtualization - only the items displayed on screen (and perhaps a few neighboring items) have their layout containers generated, so the Loaded event might be what you are looking for. You could also assume that when the getters of your view model properties (like "Provider") get accessed - these items are getting displayed, but then you need to be careful to not access them from anywhere but the DataTemplate.

Comment: Thanks Filip, i am using GridView.. how can implement virtualization?